# Run sharepoint code in asp.net application

Tags: development, 2016

In asp.net application , I wrote c# code to add item in sharepoint list  and I got error

**Microsoft SharePoint is not supported in 32-bit process**

I set the platform to 64x with no avail !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In project Properties, try to change `IIS Express` to `Local IIS` as the following:

- Open Visual Studio as administrator.
- Right click on your project > properties.
- Don't change the platform and platform target, just set it as default `any CPU`
- At web section > below servers > select Local IIS > Click on create virtual directory.
- Save and run the application that should be working.

Answer (score 2):

The server must be in 64b where you run your application, not only the configuration of platforme in VisualStudio settings.

Is your application asp.net run on the SharePoint serveur (front-end, applicative ...)?
If yes, you can use the SharePoint API Server site (in the microsoft.SharePoint.dll).
Else you should (and I recommend this) to **use the CSOM (Client SharePoint Object Model)**.

You can find a lot of doc on internet. Like :
[How to: Create, Update, and Delete List Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539976.aspx)
[SharePoint Client Object Modal (CSOM)](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-client-object-modal-csom/)